# Can I use autoencoders for dimensionality reduction with a very small dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I have a numeric dataset with just 55 samples and 270 features. I'm trying to separate these samples into clusters, however, it is hard to perform clustering in such high-dimensional space. Thus, I'm thinking about using autoencoders for performance dimensionality reduction, but I'm not sure if it is possible to do that with such a small dataset. Notice that this application is useful because the idea is to allow it to deal with different datasets that have similar characteristics.

With the following code, using Mean Squared Error as the loss function, I have achieved a loss of 4.9, which I think that is high. Notice that the dataset is already normalized.

Is it possible to use autoencoders for dimensionality reduction in this case?

This is the source for building the autoencoder and training it:

```
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import layers
from keras import regularizers
from keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

features = 0
preservationRatio = 0.99
epochs = 500

data = loadData("dataset.csv")
samples = len(data)
features = len(data[0])

x_train = data
x_test = data

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1,min_delta=0.001, patience=50)

encoding_dim = int(features*preservationRatio)

input_number = keras.Input(shape=(features,))
# Add a Dense layer with a L1 activity regularizer
encoded = layers.Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu',
                activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(1e-7))(input_number)
decoded = layers.Dense(features, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)

autoencoder = keras.Model(input_number, decoded)

encoder = keras.Model(input_number, encoded)

# This is our encoded input
encoded_input = keras.Input(shape=(encoding_dim,))
# Retrieve the last layer of the autoencoder model
decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
# Create the decoder model
decoder = keras.Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input))

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())

x_train = x_train.reshape((len(x_train), np.prod(x_train.shape[1:])))
x_test = x_test.reshape((len(x_test), np.prod(x_test.shape[1:])))
print(x_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)

history = autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=epochs,
                batch_size=20,
                callbacks=[es],
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test),
                verbose = 1)
```

Comment: Can it be used? Probably not. You would need to experiment and see for yourself. presumably, you can doing dimensionality reduction to do some other task like classification, regression etc, try it out see if the end performance that you care about increases with the reduced dataset. However, 55 samples is way too low any dataset, let alone for one that has 270 features. You probably need to collect more data. Simple as that.

Comment: I have replaced the sigmoid by a relu activation function in the decoded layer and now my loss is around 0.1.

Comment: When you use a model as complex as autoencoder with a simple dataset, it can overfit very easy. You can't be sure that the embedding it learnt is meaningful without more data (if you have two datapoints, you can make the error to be zero, doesn't mean it's a good idea)

Comment: Is there any interesting way for identifying overfitting in a model like that, @Ananda?

Comment: Besides that, if I'm just interested in reducing the dimensionality of that specific dataset, do I need to avoid overfitting? Why? Notice that I won't use the trained autoencoder in data that is not present in the training dataset.